# Using projection matrix on GLKMatrixStack

Tags: ios, matrix, opengl-es, glkit

Given this setup:

```
GLKMatrixStackRef transformHierarchy = GLKMatrixStackCreate (kCFAllocatorDefault);

float aspect = (float)self.drawableWidth / (float)self.drawableHeight;
float fov = PI * 0.125;
float height = 10.0f;
float cameraOffset = -height / (2.0f * tanf (fov / 2.0f));

GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective (fov, aspect, 0.01f, 1000.0f);
GLKMatrix4 T = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation (0.0f, 0.0f, cameraOffset);
```

I would expect these two options to create an identical matrix on the top of the stack. Option A:

```
GLKMatrixStackLoadMatrix4 (transformHierarchy, projectionMatrix);
GLKMatrixStackTranslate (transformHierarchy, 0.0f, 0.0f, cameraOffset);
```

Option B:

```
GLKMatrixStackLoadMatrix4 (transformHierarchy, GLKMatrix4Multiply (projectionMatrix, T));
```

Option A gives me a black screen:

```
3.351560 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 5.027339 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000020 25.117201 
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
```

Option B (otherwise identical matrix but with a non-zero m44) gives me the visual result I expect:

```
3.351560 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 5.027339 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000020 25.117201
0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 25.136698
```

So I've found a solution to my black screen, but the result using `GLKMatrixStackTranslate()` surprises me. Am I missing something here? Is it not considered a good practice to put the projection + world matrix at the bottom of the stack (to be followed by model transforms)?

**UPDATE**

Corrected mistake in my cameraOffset math and updated matrix output to match, although it has no effect on the problem as described. Also for clarity I transposed the matrix values (copy/pasted from xcode, which presents them in row-major order), to column-major (as OpenGL interprets them).

Also filed a bug with Apple to inquire if this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Apple determined my bug report on this issue to be a duplicate of bug 15419952. I expect people don't run into this much as they might typically keep the projection matrix separate from the model transform stack. In any case the workaround presented in the question works fine.